# Linux SAR/SAT Daily Reports to store more than a month?

Tags: linux, redhat, logging, sar

I'm on `RHEL`. How can i extend the log interval of SAR Reports to be more then a month? Normally the daily SAR reports are something like:

```
[root@server /]# cat /var/log/sa/sa
sa01      sa21      sa23      sa25      sa27      sa29      sa31      sar21     sar23     sar25     sar27     sar29     sar31     
sa20.bz2  sa22      sa24      sa26      sa28      sa30      sar20     sar22     sar24     sar26     sar28     sar30
```

It means it stores daily reports for one month only.

- How do i store (for e.g) 3 months?

Answer (score 2):

`sar` appends the day-of-month to each file, so as you've seen it will only keep one month's worth of data.

To keep more, simply archive the output to another directory. `sar` will still be able to read them using the `-f` flag.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by setting the `HISTORY` parameter to the number of days you want to keep the log files. The configuration file is `/etc/sysconfig/sysstat`. Although the maximum number of days you can set is 28, if you want to keep the saDD format log files in the `/var/log/sa` directory only, you are still allowed to set it to greater than 28 days. If set to more than 28 days, the log files will be stored in a month-by-month directory. So your sar log files will be pointing to a symlink to `YYYYMM/saDD` log file. This will be taken care of by the `sa1` script in cron.

Check out the following links for the details - [monthly sar reports](http://www.itworld.com/it-managementstrategy/290424/ez-monthly-sar-reports) and [systat facts](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/faq.html#sar) (section 2.19).